# Get Gnuplot version from pipe in C++

Tags: c++, gnuplot

In my C++ program (in linux), I can open a pipe for writing and set values for Gnuplot program.

```
FILE *pipe = NULL;

#ifdef WIN32
    pipe = _popen("pgnuplot -persist", "w");
#else
    pipe = popen("gnuplot", "w");
#endif

if(pipe == NULL)
    error("Could not open pipe for write!");

// set title name
fprintf(pipe, "set title 'Sample Points' \n");
```

Now I need to get the Gnuplot version. The `show version` command does this but how I can send this command and then read the value. Opening a pipe for reading seems to not work for me and the code stuck in the while loop without getting any data.

```
FILE* pipe = popen(command, "r");
if (!pipe)
{
    std::cout << "failed! (can not open pipe)" << endl;
    return;
}

char buffer[128];
std::string result = "";
while(!feof(pipe))
{
    if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        result += buffer;
}
pclose(pipe);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the not working part? *How* is it not working? Isn't the pipe opened? Do you get unexpected results? Doesn't it build? What?

Comment: Oh, and you should read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Di you look at https://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/ ?

Comment: Or http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since on my Debian/Linux/Sid/x86-64 the command `gnuplot --version` is outputting to `stdout` the following line:

```
 gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1
```

I would simply recommend

```
FILE* pipversion = popen("gnuplot --version", "r");
if (!pipversion) { perror("popen gnuplot"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
char lineversion[128];
memset (lineversion, 0, sizeof(lineversion));
if (!fgets(lineversion, sizeof(lineversion), pipversion) { 
    perror("fgets"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/// lineversion is like: gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1
int majvers=0, minvers=0, pos= -1;
char* restvers = NULL;
if (sscanf(lineversion, "gnuplot %d.%d %n", &majvers, &minvers, &pos) >= 2) {
  assert (pos>=0);
  restvers = lineversion+pos;
};
pclose(pipversion);
pipversion = NULL;
```

After that, `majvers` contains the major version of `gnuplot` (e.g. 5 in my case) and `minvers` contains the minor version (e.g. 0), with `restvers` being a suffix string (e.g. `"patchlevel 1"` without the quotes).

There might be a potential race condition in the unusual and unlikely case that `gnuplot` is updated between this `popen` and the next one `pipe = popen("gnuplot", "w");`. BTW, naming a variable `pipe` is poor taste, since POSIX and Linux have the [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) system call. But I don't think it is worth caring about that race condition.

BTW, you very probably want to replace your second `pipe = popen("gnuplot", "w");` with an explicit *double* invocation of   [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) (followed by appropriate [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) ...) to have both input and output pipes to `gnuplot`, and manage them in your own [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (probably around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10009205/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108) answers).

<sup>(if you application has or uses its own event loop, in particular if it is a GUI application above Qt or GTK, you want to use the same event loop for the pipes; details are specific to the library providing that event loop: [g_spawn_async_with_pipes](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async-with-pipes) & [g_source_add_unix_fd](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-add-unix-fd) for GTK, [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) for Qt ... )</sup>

I don't have time to explain how to do that (double piping into command + event loop) in details, but the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) book (available online) has several chapters on that. Be aware that you *need* some event loop.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! BTW, you forgot to set the pos value in sscanf