# using select() for I/O multiplexing

Tags: linux, concurrency, process, io

just some questions on I/O multiplexing, my textbook says:

*The select function blocks until at least one descriptor in the read set is ready for reading. A descriptor k is ready for reading if and only if a request to read 1 byte from that descriptor would not block.*

Q1-I dont't understand why read 1 byte from a descriptor might block? isn't that standard IO functions use buffer?

Q2-why not just fork a child process and let the child to do job which might block?

Q3-if I use unbuffered system call read() to read a lot of bytes from two opened files, so they're all blocking(take long long time), so how select() does de-multiplexing?

Comment: [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) tend to be obsolete. Of course you should read its documentation and also [select_tut(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html). I recommend using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) in new code (since it does not limit the highest file descriptor)

Comment: Your question shows a lot of confusion. You really should take several days in reading more. My answer gives several links.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) man page (and see also [select_tut(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html)). BTW, you'll better use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) in new code, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10009205/841108); since `select` is limiting (by the size of `fd_set`) the highest file descriptor that it can use (think of the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)).

The `select` man page defines a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))  as *ready* ...

> ... if it is possible to perform a corresponding I/O operation (e.g., [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) without blocking, or a sufficiently small [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)).

That is, if a file descriptor is such that you could successfully [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) at least one byte from it, it is a ready file descriptor (for `read`s). Most of the time, you'll be able to read several bytes from it. A file descriptor from which you cannot `read`, because a [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) attempt would block, is not ready so could be called a blocked file descriptor.

There are several cases of a file descriptor being blocked (that is, not ready). The usual one is some network [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) or some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (or some terminal, see [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) and [*the TTY demystified*](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and be aware of the [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline)) not having any more input. That is why `poll` (or `select`, [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html), etc...) is needed to code [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (in particular in [widget toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) for GUI, in Web servers, etc.), since you want to avoid busy [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)).

For further explanation, **read a good Linux programming book, such as the [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)**.

You could also read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to get more knowledge about OSes.

Be aware that [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is implementing *buffered* IO (above  [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)). See also [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to query programmatically the state of processes (most of them being [idle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(CPU)) since blocked in IO operations or event loops). Or use [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) (both are using `/proc/`) in commands.

At last, look into the source code of many [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. web servers, GUI toolkits, etc.). You can find many examples of event loops using `select` or `poll`.

Comment: so what's the circumstance that it is not ready to read one byte?

Comment: I gave several links. You are misunderstanding something essential. Take several days to read ALP. I feel that an entire book is needed to answer your question.

Comment: could you tell me first that what does  'read 1 byte from that descriptor would not block' mean, please?

Comment: I already did. Read again my answer (and follow the hyperlinks in it!), and read carefully the documentation, and read the [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) book. You need to *spend several days in reading more* (and we cannot do that effort at your place)